# Unit Test Entity Framework sets connection string to bin directory instead of App_Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, connection-string

I am trying to run Unit Tests using the Entity Framework.

When I run using debug or release I set my connection string like so:

```
#if RELEASE
        public DataContext()
            : base("Release")
        {
        }
#else
        public DataContext()
            : base("Debug")
        {
        }
#endif
```

My Connection Strings in Web.Config look like:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Debug" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdf;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Release" connectionString="MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Net=dbmssocn;Server=my.site.com;Database=mydatabase;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This works great when I simply run my Asp.Net MVC site.

But when I go to run Unit Tests, it looks in the bin directory instead of using the Debug connection string with the debug database in my App_Data directory, even if the project is build against the Debug configuration before running the tests.

The error I get is:

> *System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach
>   the file
>   'D:\Development\Projects\myproject\MyProject\bin\mydatabase.mdf*

Why is it looking in the bin directory instead of using the App_Data path defined in the connection string?

**ANSWER:**

The answer was to set the data directory in the App Domain like this in the Test Fixture Setup in my Base Test Class:

```
public class TestBase
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var appDataDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory.Replace("\\bin", ""), "App_Data");

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", appDataDirectory);
    }
}
```

Comment: what unit test are you runned? missing info. anyway your connection string should not be involved in unit testing, you have to mock your repository

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166883/connection-string-in-unit-test-project-to-reference-database-in-app-data-folder?rq=1

Comment: My Unit Test calls a Manager class that creates an instance of DataContext and executes a simple find. Why wouldn't the connection string be involved? It's calling the constructor. Also, what does 'mock your repository' mean?

Comment: @abc unit testing involve isolated code without dependency, so your  test should not have dependency to Devices ,File System or Database availability, its a wrong approach to unit testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Unit-Test project, `DataDirectory` is not set automatically. Try to set it manually yourself:

```
var appDataDir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../App_Data");

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", appDataDir);
```

Make sure you're invoking the above code before initializing EF context.

Comment: Woo hoo! This worked perfect! Thanks. That was a pain in the ass. I'm actually going to edit this just a bit to what actually worked in the end, bit it is based on your answer.